# How do I run code using reporters in BehaviorSpace?

Tags: netlogo

I am simulating a classroom to find the total energy consumption from appliances of a classroom. Now I want to run the simulation in BehaviorSpace so that I get the energy consumption by varying the number of students in the classroom.

```
 to-report energy-calculation

 ask lights [ ifelse ( l-on? )  [ set l-energy (light-on-duration * light-wattage) ][ 
 set l-energy 0 ] ]
 ask fans [ ifelse ( f-on? ) [ set f-energy ( fan-on-duration * fan-wattage )] [ set f- 
 energy 0 ] ]
 ask acs [ ifelse ( a-on? ) [ set a-energy (ac-on-duration * ac-wattage) ] [ set a- 
 energy 0 ] ]

 let light-e sum [l-energy] of lights
 let fan-e sum [f-energy] of fans
 let ac-e sum [a-energy] of acs

 set t-light ( light-e / (60000))
 set t-fan ( fan-e / (60000))
 set t-ac ( ac-e / ( 60000 ) )

 show (word "sum of ac energy = " ac-e )

 report ( t-light + t-fan + t-ac )

 end
```

In the BehaviorSpace: measure runs using these reporters I am putting energy-calculation but in the spreadsheet everything is showing zero. Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you find that `energy-calculation` reports 0 outside of BehaviorSpace, too? Or is the problem specific to the BehaviorSpace context? Offhand, I don't see any mistakes in your code, offhand. You may need to apply standard debugging techniques such as inserting additional calls to `show` to get more detailed information about what it is going on in the code.

Comment: Outside of BehaviorSpace it is not reporting 0. When I use a monitor to see this energy-calculation a value is shown. But when I am running the simulation in BehaviorSpace it is showing zero.

Comment: energy-calculation energy-calculation energy-calculation
0 0 0

Comment: I don't know why that would be; it probably involves information that you haven't provided and that I'm unable to guess at. You may need to apply standard debugging techniques, as I mentioned above.